# ERC721 Smart Contract: Best Strategy for Handling Token Metadata when Minting Partially with IPFS Storage

Tags: erc-721, meta-data

I would like to create a ERC721 contract for a situation in which I don't have all the tokens ready upfront. Let say I would like to mint 100 tokens but I have only 10 at the moment of deploying the contract, but I don't have the other 90. I will be adding them in time.

My main question comes on how should I handle the URIs of the individual tokens. So far what I have been doing with ERC721 contracts is having using the method

```
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        _requireMinted(tokenId);

        string memory baseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString())) : "";
    }
```

So basically with this method I

1. Upload all my data to IPFS
2. I have a fixed CID/URI for the folder and all the tokens are inside the folder with a name tokenID
3. I deploy the contract with a baseURI given by IPFS folder.

My current problem is that I don't have all the metadata ready, so I can't upload everything to IPFS. If I want to add something else in the future to a IPFS the baseURI is going to change. So I can't using this strategy. What can I do in this case?

I was thinking in implementing a mapping and a function to set the URI of each token individually:

```
contract MyNFT is ERC721 {
    string private baseURI;
    uint256 private tokenCounter;
    mapping(uint256 => string) private tokenURIs;

...

    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory uri) external {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI set for nonexistent token");
        tokenURIs[tokenId] = uri;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory uri = tokenURIs[tokenId];
        if (bytes(uri).length == 0) {
            uri = bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId)) : "";
        }
        return uri;
    }
```

In practice this can work, but I don't know if it is the best strategy and if gas is going to be mega expensive when I try to store URIS in the mapping.

Which is the best way to handle this situation and avoid paying lot of unnecessary gas? Is it possible actually to assign new tokens metadata after the first tokens are minted?